# Galeria de imagens (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

Bom dia, estou começando na programação web e preciso de um norte...
Quero fazer uma galeria com timthumb onde apareça várias imagens depois que clicar em alguma, ela abrir em tela cheia e seguir com um slider simples para que o usuário possa ir avançando as imagens. 
Obrigado.

Comment: Pode começar por ver uns plugins que facilitam. EX: http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Valeu Miguel, aquele Image gallery do fancybox é bem o que eu estava procurando, vou tentar implementar

Comment: Talvez [esse aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polo_norte_magn%C3%A9tico) ajude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Lightbox (jQuery)

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Acho que o script Lightbox serve exatamente para sua dúvida.

Faça o download [aqui](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/archive/master.zip) e descompacte em seu computador.

**Como usar o Lightbox**

Inclua o CSS no topo de sua página pagina em sua tag `<head>`:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lightbox Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/lightbox.min.css">
</head>
...
```

Inclua o Javascript no final de sua página antes de fechar a tag `</body>`:

```
...
  <script src="../dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Inicializar com HTML**

- Adicione um atributo `data-lightbox` para qualquer link de imagem  para habilitar o Lightbox.

  Para o valor do atributo, use um nome único para cada imagem. Por exemplo:

  `<a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>`

Opcional: Adicione um atributo `data-title` se você quiser mostrar uma legenda.

- Se você tem um conjunto de imagens relacionadas que você gostaria de combinar em um conjunto, use o mesmo valor do atributo `data-lightbox` para todas as imagens. Por exemplo:

  `<a href="images/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #2</a>
  <a href="images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #3</a>
  <a href="images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #4</a>`

---

**Exemplo online**

```css
/* Preload images */
body:after {
  content: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/dist/images/close.png) url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/dist/images/loading.gif) url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/dist/images/prev.png) url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/dist/images/next.png);
  display: none;
}

body.lb-disable-scrolling {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.lightbox a img {
  border: none;
}

.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-outerContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-container {
  padding: 4px;
}

.lb-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 0;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.lb-cancel {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/dist/images/loading.gif) no-repeat;
}

.lb-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lb-container > .nav {
  left: 0;
}

.lb-nav a {
  outline: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');
}

.lb-prev, .lb-next {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
  width: 34%;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/dist/images/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next {
  width: 64%;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/dist/images/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-dataContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-dataContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-data {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.lb-data .lb-details {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-caption {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-number {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999999;
}

.lb-data .lb-close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/dist/images/close.png) top right no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.lb-data .lb-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lightbox Example</title>

<!-- Estou chamando o arquivo lightbox.css direto do trecho de código CSS postado acima -->

<!-- Para chamar seu arquivo lightbox.css direto de seu diretório retire o comentário da tag link abaixo -->

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/lightbox.css"> -->

</head>
<body>

  <section>
    <h3>Duas imagens individuais</h3>
    <div>
      <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-1"><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-1.jpg" alt="image-1" /></a>
      <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="example-2" data-title="Optional caption."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-2.jpg" alt="image-1"/></a>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <h3>Um conjunto de 4 imagens</h3>
    <div>
      <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
      <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      <a class="example-image-link" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <p>
      Para mais informações, visite <a href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/">http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/</a>
    </p>
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.2/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Para chamar seu arquivo lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js direto de seu diretório retire o comentário da tag script abaixo -->

<!-- <script src="../dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script> -->


</body>
</html>
```

---

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, tem um monte de template de HTML/CSS pronto, só fica a cabo de ti implentar o php da sua pagina. Segue um exemplo:

```
Galeria 1 http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page2/photobusiness

Galeria 2 https://templated.co/visualize
```

Segue ai, to começado também! ;)

Comment: Valeu cara, muito obrigado.

Comment: De nada cara! tmj!